# DiscoveryClient.GetAsync cannot connect to server

Tags: identityserver4

I have an issue when I am trying to set up this code:

```
var discoClient = new DiscoveryClient("http://localhost:5000") {Policy = 
{RequireHttps = false}};
var disco = await discoClient.GetAsync();
```

The second line, var disco, tells me that it had issues connecting to the server, and I am at a loss trying to figure out why.

I am going through this tutorial: https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html.
I have everything else up to that point setup just like the walkthrough

What do I need to do to make this work?

Comment: Which package version of IdentityServer4 are you using?

Comment: I am using v2.0.1

Comment: Did you make sure that both projects, the IdentityServer4, and the client, are running?

Comment: Please be sure to add the error message too.

Comment: The error message when I breakpoint the MainAsync method, which contains the above code, says "Error connecting to http://localhost:5000/.well-known/openid-configuration: An error occurred while sending the request." As far as both projects running, they are in the same solution, so I'm not quite sure how I would check that

Comment: if you try the URL 'localhost:5000/.well-known/openid-configuration' from your browser do you get a response?

Comment: ok, so it does not connect there

Comment: Set the IdentityServer4 as your startup project and run that by itself.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Doing that I realized that I was still only running current selection for the startup process, so the 5000 port was not running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have both projects running.

In Solution Explorer select the solution file at the top.

Then right click and select the properties menu option.

Select the 'Multiple startup projects' and make sure the IdentityServer and Client Projects are set to 'Start'.